# TYPO3 Indexed Search Engine - not all the page content is indexed

Tags: indexing, content-management-system, typo3

I have a TYPO3 site with Indexed Search Engine extension...
The problem is that not all the content is indexed (with debug option activated in conf content not all the page is present but the page size is corect), only the firts part of the page (witch is the head/title and the begining of the menu...).
So for every page the words are only from the begining of the page (title, menus).
I have tried using the Indexed Search Engine begin and end tags but no effect...
What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am stupid :-( I have figured out the problem...
The begin/end tags where not corect I used `<!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin>`
`<!--TYPO3SEARCH_end>` insted
of  `<!--TYPO3SEARCH_begin-->` `<!--TYPO3SEARCH_end-->`